# How do I populate the Comments under this Blog Post using .populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, router, mongoose-populate

I created models with ObjectID ref. In my post request respond. It populate the comment under the post but it doesnt work on get request. Please what am I missing?

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {

  try {
    
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate("comments")
    
    res.send(post)

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.send(error)
  }
});
```

This is the response I get: It doesnt show the comments

```
{
    "comments": [],
    "_id": "5f9d2cf2f851f6214cff96e6",
    "title": "My First Blog Post",
    "post": "This is the content as Edited",
    "user": "5f9d26bf5cf5e91a6441b0e3",
    "createdAt": "2020-10-31T09:22:58.453Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-10-31T09:26:01.685Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you added new comments to your comment collection? I mean, if it doesn't populate, it should at least return the ids of comments. also put your schema code too.